# 'Unsupported Filling Mode' error while sending order from Python API to Meta Trader 5

Tags: python, mql5, metatrader5

I am developing a Python program. When I try to send an order from Python to Meta Trader 5 (Alpari broker), I get an error:

> Unsupported Filling Mode

I tried the following code:

```
# Import the libraries
import MetaTrader5 as mt5
from datetime import datetime
 
# Create the bound between MT5 and Python
mt5.initialize()
 
# Place buy order

# Initialization value
symbol = "EURUSD"
lot = 0.01
 
# Choose the deviation
deviation = 10

# Find the filling mode of symbol
filling_type = mt5.symbol_info(symbol).filling_mode
 
# Create dictionary request
request = {
     "action": mt5.TRADE_ACTION_DEAL,
     "symbol": symbol,
     "volume": lot,
     "type": mt5.ORDER_TYPE_SELL,
     "price": mt5.symbol_info_tick(symbol).bid,
     "deviation": deviation,
     "type_filling": filling_type,
     "type_time": mt5.ORDER_TIME_GTC
}
 
mt5.order_check(request)
```

The result was as below:

```
 OrderCheckResult(retcode=10030, balance=0.0, equity=0.0, profit=0.0,
 margin=0.0, margin_free=0.0, margin_level=0.0, comment='Unsupported
 filling mode', request=TradeRequest(action=1, magic=0, order=0,
 symbol='EURUSD', volume=0.01, price=1.0793, stoplimit=0.0, sl=0.0,
 tp=0.0, deviation=10, type=1, type_filling=1, type_time=0,
 expiration=0, comment='', position=0, position_by=0))
```

Can anyone help me to make this problem fixed? How I can translate the  [SYMBOL_FILLING_MODE](https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/constants/environment_state/marketinfoconstants#symbol_filling_mode) to the [ENUM_ORDER_TYPE_FILLING](https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/constants/tradingconstants/orderproperties#enum_order_type_filling) value?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would put the output in a code block for easier reading.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've experienced the same issue just now, and I realized I haven't allow the Algo Trading option in MT5 terminal

You need to configure the MT5 terminal to allow automated trading.
Here are the steps:

- Open the MT5 terminal and go to Tools > Options.
- In the Options window, go to the Expert Advisors tab.
- Check the box next to Allow automated trading.
- Check the box next to Allow DLL imports.
- Click OK.
- Finally you need to click the "Algo Trading" button on the menu bar, ensure it's in green color

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Having this turned off will return "comment='AutoTrading disabled by client'" and not "Unsupported filling mode". IDK why this is selected as the answer. @eugeny Nik has the correct answer

Answer (score 2):

Simple add to request
"type_filling": mt5.SYMBOL_FILLING_IOC

Comment: it is called "ORDER_FILLING_IOC". But yes, this is the solution

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue for two days now and I tried all the prescriptions but didn't solve but eventually this was how i resolved it.

First thing is to make sure that your mt5 is configured to receive algo trading as previously said above. Goto Tools to Options to Exert Advisors, and tick boxes to allow algorithmic trading, allow DLL imports and allow WebRequest, and untick all other four boxes.

Finally go to your order dictionary preparation and try the several "type_filling" options. **"type_filling":mt5.ORDER_FILLING_FOK** worked perfectly for me. You could try other types such as mt5._XXX_RETURN or mt5._XXX_IOC too to see which one works for you.

Answer (score -1):

It may be that your order type is not supported or the stop/tp/lot are too small.

In your case it could be because there is no money in the account. Try to do the same with a demo account that has money and see if you sill get the same error

Also check if your take profit or stop loss are too close to the opening price
Here is a list of your options.

ORDER_TYPE_BUY

ORDER_TYPE_SELL

ORDER_TYPE_BUY_LIMIT

ORDER_TYPE_SELL_LIMIT

ORDER_TYPE_BUY_STOP

ORDER_TYPE_SELL_STOP

ORDER_TYPE_BUY_STOP_LIMIT

ORDER_TYPE_SELL_STOP_LIMIT

ORDER_TYPE_CLOSE_BY